# Using structs as parameters

Tags: c, struct

This time it's about using a struct as a parameter. In this assignment I have to create a FIFS  queue system. The static person queue is of the size 10. It means that just 10 persons can be on the queue.

I also have variables head, tail and nbr_elem of type static. The tail variable is used to add the person  in a specific position. And vice_versa for the variable head. nbr_elem is the amount of persons in the queue. I think you don't need more information to help me. Now to the question:

How can I use a struct as a parameter in a function? This is what I have done so far:

```
    static person queue[QUEUE_MAX_SIZE];
static int head = 0, tail = 0, nbr_elem = 0;
 struct  person
{
    char first_name[7];
    char sur_name[10];
    char pers_nbr[10];

};


void person_info(struct person p1){


    /*printf("First name: ");*/
    scanf("%s", &p1.first_name[7]);
   /* printf("Last name: ")*/;
    scanf("%s", &p1.sur_name[10]);
    /*printf("Id-number: ");*/
    scanf("%s", &p1.pers_nbr[10]);
}
```

everything is fine so far but now I have to put struct person p1 in the queue by first copying the inf using the strcpy-function and then putting it to the array person queue[QUEUE_MAX_SIZE] i guess(?)

```
 void enqueue( person queue[QUEUE_MAX_SIZE])
{
    queue[person_info(p1.first_name[7])];
}
```

I don't even know if this is a good start of the function enqueue so I need some help here. And how can I use the static person queue[QUEUE_MAX_SIZE] in the function?

I also have a header-file queue.h that contains the typedef person. The header-file is then called to queue.c which is this file.

Comment: You are updating a copy of your original structure. You need to return the modified structure from your function (or go with [Joachim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19880113/2455888)).

Answer (score 1):

With the function

```
void person_info(struct person p1)
```

the structure is passed *by value*, that is a copy is made and you modify only this copy. You want to pass it by reference, which in C is done by passing as a pointer:

```
void person_info(struct person *p1)
```

---

You `scanf` calls in the function is *very* wrong by the way. It will write *beyond* the arrays in the structure instance. Just use e.g.

```
scanf("%6s", p1.first_name);
```

Continuing reading your question, it seems you have some very basic misunderstandings of how to use arrays, so I suggest you go back and re-ready a chapter about arrays and array indexing in the nearest book or tutorial.

In fact, considering your basic misuse of arrays, I doubt you will understand a concept such as pointers immediately, so I recommend you go and read some books and tutorials about that subject as well.

Comment: yeah I realized now that the scanf is wrong, there shouldn't be any [7] at the end.